# Public avaiable DB2 Databases

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-connect

Are there any public available Versions of the following Database:
Database: DB2 for i5/OS
Version: 07.01.0000 OS/400 V7R1M0

I´m looking either for an way to setup that specific database, or a public available one (just to connect)

Thank you.

Comment: This question belongs on dba.stackexchange.com, not here. See the FAQ.  When you post it there, please explain in more detail what you are asking.  Very little setup or administration is required on DB2 for i.

Comment: Thank you WarrenT, i´ll post it there.